# How do I add .Net C# class extension of System.Array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, class, extension-methods

I am quite familiar with class extensions, but wasn't expecting the following behavior.

I expected the following to extend System.Array, but it didn't. Instead, it extended **instances** of System.Array. Why?

```
public static T[] Concatenate<T>(this Array value1, Array value2)
{
    int l1 = value1 == null ? 0 : value1.Length;
    int l2 = value2 == null ? 0 : value2.Length;

    T[] result = new T[l1 + l2];

    if (l1 > 0)
    {
        Array.Copy(value1, 0, result, 0, l1);
    }

    if (l2 > 0)
    {
        Array.Copy(value2, 0, result, l1, l2);
    }

    return result;
}
```

...

Array. // no Concatenate

```
string[] s = new string[1];
s.Concatenate<string>... // appears here
```

Comment: I would question your assertion that you're "quite familiar with class extensions" - assuming you mean extension methods, this is perfectly normal behaviour. Time to read up on extension methods again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you can only define extension methods for instances of types. To invoke them you either use the instance-method invocation like syntax

```
var result = s.Concatenate(t);
```

or the standard static-method invocation syntax

```
var result = ArrayExtensions.Concatenate(s, t);
```

Again, you can not add methods to `Array`, only to instances of `Array` (and really, you aren't adding methods, it's just a compiler trick that makes it look like you did).

By the way, I would just write your method as

```
return value1.Concat(value2).ToArray();
```

Comment: I don't get your suggestion. Concat works on strings, not arrays.

Comment: @IanC: I used [`System.Linq.Enumerable.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

> I expected the following to extend System.Array, but it didn't. Instead, it extended instances of System.Array. Why?

Because there is no way to define static extensions method - only instance extension method can be defined ([From MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)):

> Extension methods are a special kind of static method, but they are called as if they were instance methods on the extended type.

However, you can call your extension method in static manner, but using your class extension name:

```
MyExtensions.Concatenate(s, f);
```

It's very Pythonic way to define methods.